# using grep to find filenames with accented characters or ñ in the search term

Tags: grep

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use (e)grep to list files in a directory when my search term includes Spanish characters such as accented vowels or "ñ" (e.g. bebé, caña). In the case of accented vowels, if I use the unaccented vowel, the search works as in the following:

```
$ ls | egrep 'bebe'
8 bebé
IMQ_bebé1.wav
IMQ_bebé2.wav
IMQ_bebé3.wav
IMQ_bebé4.wav
IMQ_bebé5.wav
IMQ_bebé6.wav
```

However, if I include the accented vowel in the search term, (e.g. `$ ls | egrep 'bebé'`)
I get nothing.

The reason why using non-accented vowels in the search term is not possible is because this is part of a larger shell script that gets it's search terms from a text file. Also, search terms with "ñ" don't work, nor do they work with just "n". Plus, I'm sure there must be a way to do this!

I'm working on Mac OS X 10.6.8. My locale is as follows:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Filesystem being used?  Is the matching being done exclusively for content from the filesystem (directory and/or file names)?

Comment: I'm working on Mac OS X 10.6.8, which uses the Mac OS Extended (HFS Plus) file system.

Comment: Yes, Iꞌm matching content from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iconv to unaccent your list and match ascii patterns:

```
ls | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | egrep 'bebe'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the search patterns are coming from a text utf8 text file. Also, when I use this command I get an error: 
    `$ ls | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | egrep 'bebé'
    iconv: (stdin):14:10: cannot convert`

Comment: @KevinPenner, that error indicates that `iconv` found characters that couldn't be transliterated.  You can have `iconv` ignore those characters instead (if you assume that they might not be part of the content you want to match).  Otherwise, you might want to dig deeper (I think that's on line 14, column 10).